# 2 paypal payments in 1 shot

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

Using a paypal business account to embed the paypal payment system into my website.  Is it possible to pay to another account at the same time?

For example, I want to provide a service, for which I receive a certain amount, and another paypal user receives a certain amount at the same time.

So for example, the user should simply see that they are going to pay me $10, but in the background I only want $5 to go to my paypal account, and I want the other $5 to go straight to another account which is not mine.

If that is not possible, then the following will have to do if possible:

When the user paying gets to the paypal screen, is it possible for him/her to see that s/he will be paying me $5 amount and $5 amount will be going to someone else showing a total amount of $10 about to be paid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.webpayments.ie/blog/PayPal-Adaptive-Payments-a-flexible-payments-API-from-PayPal.html

Comment: Excellent link.  Thanks.  But just 1 thing.  Must all payment receivers have business accounts, or can it be a mixture of business and personal paypal accounts?

Comment: I'm not sure but I think it can be a mixture, though for personal accounts there are some limits applied.

Answer (score -2):

www.x.com is the link to PayPal developer portal where they have specs for Adaptive Payments